# Using a Virtual in Mongoose to return full name on a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to do a find query with mongoose and get results returned with full Name of a User. Right now, I have 2 fields, firstName and lastName. When I query the database, I would like mongoose to concatenate firstName and lastName and return a field called fullName.  Is this possible with Mongoose?

The alternative would be to query the database, get the results, and loop through each object and assign the fullName on each iteration of the loop.  I feel that there is someway I can utitilize the mongoose virtual somehow.

```
UserSchema
.virtual('name.full')
   .get(function () {
   return this.name.firstName + ' ' + this.name.lastName; 
});
```

Example query:

```
User.find().exec()
.then(function(data){
    console.log(data);  //Should print out [{ _id: 123123232322, firstName:'john', lastName: 'Doe'}]
    //I would like it to print out: [{ _id: 123123232322, firstName:'john', lastName: 'Doe', fullName: 'John Doe'}]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have virtuals appear in your `console.log` output by setting the [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject) option on `UserSchema` to `{ getters: true }`:

```
UserSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
```